# Access self-hosted web server from WAN and LAN with FQDN

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, reverse-proxy, webmin

I have self-hosted web-server in internal network which i can access from external network with FQDN. I would like to access same server from internal network with same FQDN also.

I have configured my router to use my own DNS-server which is located in my internal network. I can access that and other machines with FQDN via SSH in my internal network, which has A-records in my DNS-server. But i cannot access that web-server (and actually one other "not internet facing" web-server) with FQDN via browser. I can access those with internal IP via browser.

I guess this is DNS related problem.
I know something about basic networking and servers, but when it comes to DNS, i'm out of luck.

**Related equipment:**

- **Ubiquiti Edgerouter** acting router+firewall. Configured to use internal DNS-server. FW port forward ports 80 and 443 to my Reverse Proxy.
- **Nginx reverse-proxy server** handling LetsEncrypt certs and forwarding traffic to my web-server. <-- seems to work fine(can access that web-server from external network with FQDN. SSL work also).
- **Web-server using Apache2.** Browser can access with local IP, not FQDN.

**EDIT:**

- **Nameserver** - Records created with Webmin GUI

Any ideas?

Comment: Describe what happens when you try to access the server with FQDN.

Comment: From external network: Everything looks fine. Site works as it should, SSL and SSL-redirect works. From internal: browser says basic: "Unable to connect"

Comment: "Problem loading page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about ubiquiti gear, but could be a hairpin nat missing.

The [docs](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/204952134-EdgeRouter-Hairpin-NAT) says it's enabled by default when you forward a port, but worth checking it.

Comment: Looks like it was that Hairpin NAT. Thanks for advice! However Certificates does not work. That's because my Reverse-Proxy handles those, not server itself. Maybe i'm gonna just change Certification handling to server itself. If you don't have advice for that?

Comment: Actually i got certificates working by pointing my internal A-records to my reverse-proxy. I lose ability to ssh in exposed server with DNS record but that's not a big problem